# Difference scene.layout & scene.Group

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

What is the difference between layout class (`AncorPane`,`BorderPane`,`etc`) and `Group` class?

What is the difference If I write:

```
1).
Group root = new Group();
 root .getChildren().addAll(....);

new Scene(root);
```

with

```
2). 

AncorPane root = new  AncorPane();

root .getChildren().addAll(....);

new Scene(root);
```

Or with ( *this is even confusing me more* )

```
 3). 


Group root = new Group();

AncorPane anchor= new  AncorPane();

anchor.getChildren().addAll();


Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.setRoot(anchor); <--- ?? this also confusing for me
```

I run `2)` & `3)` they are just same,.

Thanks.

Comment: 3) is identical to 2). `Scene scene = new Scene(...); scene.setRoot(x);` is the same as `Scene scene = new Scene(x);`.

Comment: @James_D, thanks for your answer on that link, I'm reading it now..i wish i could mark that answer too,